# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in long_scalars

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy, runtime-error

I'm having an issue with modifying an array, by adding the percentage of each item compared to its row to a new matrix. This is the code providing error:

```
for j in range(1,27):
        for k in range(1,27):
                let_prob[j,k] = let_mat[j,k]*100/(let_mat[j].sum())
```

I get the error:

> RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in long_scalars

I have tried rounding the denominator to no success.

Answer (score 7):

If it provides any help for other persons encountering this warning, it appeared in a similar context, where I was dividing a value with another, and the warning appeared in cases where I was dividing by 0. Adding a special-case with the value of the denominator, and avoiding a zero-division, made the warning disappear.

I don't know why that warning appeared instead of a ZeroDivisionError.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are dealing with big numbers, since it raised the error `RuntimeWarning`. To get rid of such errors, as a numpythonic way you can first calculate the sum of each row using the `np.sum()` function by specifying the proper axis then repeat and reshape the array in order to be able to divide with your array, them multiple with 100 and round the result:

```
col, row = np.shape(let_mat) 
let_prob = np.round((let_mat/np.repeat(let_mat.sum(axis=1),row).reshape(col, row).astype(‌​float))*100,2)
```

Demo :

```
>>> a = np.arange(20).reshape(4,5)
>>> 
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19]])

>>> np.round((a/np.repeat(a.sum(axis=1),5).reshape(4,5).astype(float))*100,2)
array([[  0.  ,  10.  ,  20.  ,  30.  ,  40.  ],
       [ 14.29,  17.14,  20.  ,  22.86,  25.71],
       [ 16.67,  18.33,  20.  ,  21.67,  23.33],
       [ 17.65,  18.82,  20.  ,  21.18,  22.35]])
```

Comment: @twallien You don't need to use loop, just change your array name with `a`

Comment: I tried with the replacement but due to the reshape it came out with a "ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged". I tried replacing the values in reshape with np.shape(a) and the repeat argument with np.shape(a)[1] but still returned an error.

Comment: @twallien Is `a` your `let_mat` array?

Comment: yes, this is the code: `shape = np.shape(let_mat)
let_prob = np.round((let_mat/np.repeat(let_mat.sum(axis=1),shape[1]).reshape(shape).astype(float))*100,2)`

Comment: @twallien I think you need to unpack your shape. Use `reshape(*shape)`

Comment: the shape is (27,27), and im still receiving a runtime error, due to "invalid value encountered in true_divide"

Comment: @twallien I just edited the comment, use unpacking operation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100315/discussion-between-twallien-and-kasramvd).